# Как привязать домен, купленный на reg.ru к сайту, написанном ну replit

Tags: домен

Всем привет! Написала сайт на replit и теперь пытаюсь привязать домен, купленный на reg.ru к готовом сайту в replit. Не понимаю, какие данные где брать и куда что вводить для привязки домена (Судя по всему, в reg.ru нужно или ввести DNS двух серверов, или IP-адрес). Но replit тоже при привязке домена показывает какие-то данные: А, SNAME и TXT. Скриноты привязки домена на реплите и на реге прикрепляю ниже. Буду очень признательна, если кто-то поможет разобраться что куда вводить...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3cW5.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]